# MySQL minimum value column name for minimum value

Tags: mysql, sql

My table `table1` is like below

```
id date         name     d1    d2     d3     d4
1  20/10/2017   bimal    6     7      8      9
2  20/10/2017   kumar    13    10     11     12
3  20/10/2017   aman     16    17     14     15
4  20/10/2017   halim    19    21     23     25
```

Output table is like as

```
id date         name     d1    d2     d3     d4   min_val_col    min_val_col_name
1  20/10/2017   bimal    6     7      8      9    6              d1
2  20/10/2017   kumar    13    10     11     12   13             d1
3  20/10/2017   aman     16    17     14     15   16             d1
4  20/10/2017   halim    19    21     23     25   19             d1
```

I am unable to write the query how I will complete `min_val_col_name` field? If I total column wise, `min_val_col` field is the minimum value column.`d1` column is set as `min_val_col`. I want `minimum value column name` in the `min_val_col_name`  field.

Comment: I feel like we’ve been over this already. Either fix your broken design, or don’t bother using an RDBMS.

Comment: @ Strawberry  If you kindly check, this is not the same question as marked by you. Before was on row wise minimum value. Here column wise minimum value, i.e. sum of column wise minimum value.

Comment: It’s still a problem of poor design. Fix your schema as per my suggestion and your problem will magically disappear.